# Minimize Least Used Binary Bits in Fractions

Tags: code-challenge, optimization, math

### Introduction

For a given rational number `r`, find a pair of integers `p,q` so that `p/q=r` and the number of less used bits in `p` and `q` are minimized (details below).

### Challenge

A positive rational number `r` can be expressed as the ratio of two positive integers, `r=p/q`. The representation is not unique. For each of these representations, both `p` and `q` can be expressed in its binary form and the number of `0`s and `1`s in the representation can be counted (not including leading zeros).

We count the number of appearance of the less appeared digit for both `p` and `q` (denoted `g(p)` and `g(q)`) and finally define `f(p,q)=max(g(p),g(q))`.

For example, the number `35` can be written as `35/1` or `175/5`, and we convert both the numerator and the denominator to binary. Then we can count

```
35 -> 100011, 3 zeros, 3 ones. g(35)=min(3,3)=3
 1 ->      1, 0 zero ,  1 one.  g(1)=min(1,0)=0

f(35,1)=max(g(35),g(1))=3.
```

And for `175/5`

```
175 -> 10101111. 2 zeros, 6 ones. g(175)=min(2,6)=2
  5 ->      101. 1 zero,  2 ones.   g(5)=min(1,2)=1.

f(175,5)=max(g(175),g(5))=2.
```

Therefore, if we want to minimize `f(p,q)` while keeping the rate of `p/q` constant, `p=175,q=5` is a better choice than `p=35,q=1`. An even better choice is `p=1015,q=29` since `f(1015,29)=1`. It is also easy to prove that there are no valid choice that makes `f(p,q)` equals `0`, so this the optimal choice.

Your task is to write a full program or function that computes a choice of `(p,q)` for a given rational number `r` such that `f(p,q)` is minimized (sub-optimal solutions are OK but there are penalties), while keeping the program as short as possible.

### Test cases

The outputs are not unique.

```
Input
Output

63/1
63/1 0

17/9
119/63 1

35/1
1015/29 1

563/1
2815/5 2
```

You may also wish to see whether you can get an answer without penalty(see below) for `595/1`.

### Scoring

Your score will be composed of two parts: the code-length and the penalties. The code-length is measured in bytes.

The penalties are calculated by running your program on all test cases in the given test set. For each `r` in the test set, if your program outputs `p,q`, you get a penalty of `max(f(p,q)-2,0)`. That is, you get no penalty (nor bounty) for any answer that gives a `f` value less than or equal to `2`.

The final score is calculated by `final_penalty*codelength^(1/4)`, with lower score better.

### Test set

The test set for calculating the penalty can be found in this
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0rzNRt6F).

Basically, it contains all rational numbers which when expressed in reduced fraction `p/q` has the property `128>p>q` (and of course, `(p,q)` coprime), along with all integers from `128` to `1023`(inclusive). The second column in the pastebin are the `f(p,q)` calculated by a naive method. The final line in the pastebin shows the total penalty of this naive method. It is `2343`.

### Specs

- Input can be given in any reasonable form. For example, a rational if your program supports it, or a tuple or a list of the numerators and denominators in any order (and you should assume them to be coprime). Same flexiblility for output.
- You need to output `p` and `q` in a reasonable form and also `f(p,q)` (To avoid 0-byte programs, thanks to @Lynn).
- You should be able to score your own program (Thanks for the suggestion by @user202729). So in your answer, please specify all of the following: the final penalty, the code length in bytes, and the score. Only the score needs to be included in the title of your answer.

Comment: Sandbox post: [deleted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/15014#15014)

Comment: (which naive method?)

Comment: Enumerating all cases up to a limit.

Comment: There are languages in which the 0-byte program copies input to output. This is a valid answer that scores a perfect score of `0` by the `final_penalty*codelength^(1/4)` formula, so you might want to tweak it.

Comment: Changed to require that `f(p,q)` be included in the output.

Comment: Can I output only the multiplier (`p'/p`) and `f(p',q')`?

Comment: If I programmed correctly, [this program](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43770061#43770061) computes the optimal result, and total penalty is 2330, and the largest multiplier is 261599.

Answer (score 3):

## Node.js, Score = 7873

This is both naive and rather long...

- Code size = 129 bytes
- Total penalty = 2336
- Score = round(129<sup>1/4</sup> * 2336) = 7873

Takes input as **[p, q]**. Returns **[p', q', f(p, q)]**.

```javascript
f=(a,r=[k=6e3])=>k--?f(a,(i=Math.max(...a.map(n=>(g=n=>n?g(n>>1,n&1?++o:++z):o<z?o:z)(a=(p=a,n*k),o=z=0))))>r[2]?r:[p,a,i],k--):r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc3BaoQwEAbge58ipzKpMXEM2ho6yRP0CcRD2Kq1bhPJLqX48jaXpbD9D8MwfMz/6b/95ZSW7VqG@D4ex0TgRaJ@pXbUAye7lqWb8g0WevPXD/nlf0BK6fOyQSALM@UZ3AzBWhThEV1RRFMUOzfxdXfR7Bw8wUZehKeVi0g7VTzHpr4eXDL9JrxYBpGbuEnHKYZLPI/yHGeYoG@1wIFzxpRirVbIcqqHO4TPorshxE61mjG8R7r5@4QVNqru/qPm1pdR/ZJRw1h9/AI) for the test cases

or [compute the total penalty](https://tio.run/##Tb3fjnTJceR5r6foq0Vz2SLSPcL/cbdJzAPMExC86NFQGq1mSIHSLgZ6eW1l@s9OkQC/qK4T4ZmVEebhZnZOxv/zy//3y7/9w1//@V///e///Jf//qf//M9//PnHX376689/@Jef80/nj7/6@Xf/8vd///t//Prdj//883/95d//x2/@1y//@8ff/OY3v3z98K8//vnn3/34Tz9//fvn3//Tj3/@3e/spz//H/b7X//6L7/99a//41e//cv//R@//8tv/@NXP/7y84//@vMvP/35//yXX/30l5//4@fXr77@97u//sH/@Pu//vYP//rTLz/98x9/@nqlX/32r//5X374@Yc//N0PP/zBf7I//vSHw7/@9e/9/Hx/Ol//xufn@Pw@@M39@jc/v8@f4uvf@vxcnz716VOfPsXV/Pq3P336c7U/v@@f6uvf@fx@PmPnM2o@V4er/fWvvT6dvpqzTW0z78b2mn0ifDVnm7tNbJPb1Da9jYa/3u1@Cl9NbFP88vPb/XBsP52v5mxzt4ltcpvaprcZhr9oFe4TaD9n2w/6q4lthmtctM/VnQfbibCdg6@mtmm60OcZ8um1U/XVnG1im9pm6EIfo5N9eu3M2k6t7dzaTq7t7NpO71dT2/Q2w/AXLXGMQEYkI9Tzcp9gu1hs14ntQnn/kt/u4K/28/tdQbZL6Ks529xtYpvchgG9zTD8RUscI5ARyQhlxDKCPS//Due7Rn3XqO8a9V2j72tcNK4al@1zfdew7xr2Xby@i9d3uTrr9N3Sd0PZvp13W7SE9E//Xddfzdkmtqlthi5cNK4al43r/omxKPBFgS8KfFHgiwJfFPiiwBcFvihwUOCgwEHBuyWSEcqIZQQzohnhjHhOPL09/8RbVPnC6aspfslv98UuQS/B7k/@@f3CzBdmvgnPF21fTW5T2/Q2wzgGGiNN8RhrDDZGG8ON8a4XZrzej3/GL4Z9MeyLYV8M@2LYwbCD3XfLZeO6c90J4p9@i3FfjPuC2xfcvqj2RbUDZwfODowdGDvwfbcM21cuZqr444p3UM878M@4hb3vJuGL/q9muMZF46pxeV@rea0mdhP7q/1c3yzhmyV8s4RvlvDNEr5ZwjdL@GYJ3yzhZAknSzhZwskSTpZwsoSTJZws4coSw9scPpJhUoaPZnj7w7wPf8bwEc3z5/g73tmsczbdHPLMIc8c8swhz3y1zu/989@bd87mnbN759n0czb9nN07z@6dZ5PR2b3zkJMOOendEsiIZIQyYhnBjGhGOCOeE8/1vojnxHPiOfGceE48J57@vPOJR4WzOfBsDjybA8/mwMNOf8iFh1x4yIWHXHjIhe@Wfk4/p5/T73z6UVZtzjybLM8my7NZ8myWPKTHQzo8pMNDGjykwUP6O6S/d0t/J6rT34nr9Nc7Op/3smnybPFxNluezZZna5BD0jwkzXdLL@O6c9257lx3wjj9jl7r02@T7NkkezbJnk2yZ5Ps2ex6Nrsesushux6y6yGrHrLqIasesuohmx6y6SGbvlvGOeOc/ofXOXprjDufcZuFz6bfs@n3kHcPtdMh7x7y7iHfHvLtu@X3h3Hn8/vNw2fz8Nla62w6PpuOz9ZaZ7Py2ax8ttY6JOdDcj7UWockfUjSh1rrkKwPyfrdEs6I58RzvS/iOfGceE48J54Tz4nnxDvEO8Q7@kOJd4inj@N84u2mcHZTOLspnC0Jz@4Nh73hsDcc9obD3vDVOted685113XiHL0W/Q79zqff7iFn95Czm8fZzePsrnF21zhsF4ft4rA9HLaFw7Zw2A4O28FhGzhsA4f0f5Tuh3c6vNPhQxw@vOEdz/OOz3vc3W3ibnF6d7e4W5xeNo3LpnHZNC6bxlfrXHeuO9ed60fBuX64fj7Xd5O5u8nc3WTubjJ3N5m7m8zdTebuJnN3k7lsMpdN5rLJXDaZyyZz2WQum8xlk7lsMpdN5rLJXDaZyyZz2WQum8xlk7lsMpdN5rLJXDaZyybzbol39IcS7xDvEO8Q7xDvEE8f1/3E203r7m512Z8u@9NlX7rsS5f96LIfXfahyz70bul/P/@9@9KF728tf3d7urs93a3l7@5Sd3epu7X8ZbO61PKXWv6yeV02r0stf9nELpvYpZa/bGaXzexSy19q@cvm9m6J58Rz4jnxnHhOvEO8Q7yjP5R4h3iHeId4h3iHeId4l3j6@O4nHkrJbqJ3N9G7m@jdTfSyeV42zwvzuGyil030soleNtHLJnrZRC@b6Lvl@uH64frl@v3E2U327iZ7d3e9y13u7q6XbfWynV7IymVbvWyrl@30sp1ettPLNvpuief0O8Q99D/EPcQ79L/001u@n367zd4lO3d327u77V2yc9l0L5vuhfRcNt/L5nshPZfN991y3bl@9FrEOfQ79Dv0u/S79Luffrtp3920727adzftu5v23U377qZ9d9O@u2lfNu3Lpn3ZtC@b9mXTvmzal037smlfNu3Lpn3ZtC@b9mXTvmzal037smlfNu3Lpn3ZtC@b9mXTvmzal037smlfNu3Lpn3ZtN8t8Q7xDvEu8S7xLvGuPjni6eO9n3hbBNzd/e/u/pdt/7LtX7b7CxW8bPeX7f6yzV@2@cv2ftnev9rL7y/j7uf3u@3f3fbvUse7u//d3f8udby7@9/ljJci4FIEXDjjhTNeuOKlKLgUBReueCkOLsXBpTi4FAcXjngpEi4c8cIRL8XC@x0z/vA@jv4S4hziHMYfxh/exyHOJc4lztVHwfjL@7jE0ed333Fii5DYIiS2CIktQoIiJChCgiIkKEKCIiQoQoIiJChCgiIkKEKCIiQoQr7ay/XL9cv1@7m@RUpskRJbncRWJ7FlSWxZEtQjQT0S1CFBHRLUH0G9EdQbQZ0R1BlBfRHUF0FdEdQVQT0R1BNB/RDUDUHdENQL75b@l/iX93OJfxmnvzg@47bOiCXHseVGLDmOJcdB8RGQ4qD4CIqPgBQHRUhQhASkOChGgmLk3dLv0O/Q73L9cv1y/eo6ceLTb4uY2CImtoiJLWJii5jYIia2iIktYmKLmKCICYqYoIgJipigiAmKmKCICYqYoIgJipigiAmKmKCICYqYoIgJipigiAmKmKCICYqYoIgJipigiAmKmKCICYqYoIgJipigiAmKmKCICYqYoIh5t/rkiHeJd4l3iXeJd4kXxNN0xCfeFkWx1VBsNRRoCUE5FJRBQRkUlD9B@ROUPUHZE5Q9QdkTlDtBufNu9XvGxef3@FcYWDhYWw3Fag2xRVFsURQrOQRSQ1AbBbVRUBsFtVEgOQQ1UiDkBjVSIDkEtVIgOQQ1U1AzBTVTUDMFNdO7Zdxh3GHcYdxl3GXc1Z/IuMu4y7jLuGBcME6fV3xed2uw2BostgaLLb6C4isovoLiKyi@guIrUD6C4isovoLiKyi@guIrKLqCoisouoKiKyi63i39guuhd/m5vkVZbFEWW43FVmOxZVhsGRbUX0H9FdRdQd0V1FtBvRXUV0FdFdRVQT0V1FNBHRXUUUH9FNRPQd0U1E1BvRTUR0F9FNRFQV0U1EPvVv2JH4wL4gfj9InEZ9zWUbFiSmw5FVtOxYopQVUVVFWBmBJUV0F1FYgqQZUVVFmBqBJUWYGYElRbQbX1bolz6Xfpd@l36XfpF/QLvXn6xaffVmmxVVpslRZbpcVWabFVWqxUE1usxRZrQbEWFGtBsRYUa4GCExRtQdEWFG1B0RYUbUHRFgj8QfEWFG9B8RYUb0HxFhRvgeITFHFBERcUcUERFxRxQREXKEBBMRcUc0ExFxRzQTEXFHPvlnhXnxzxLvEu8S7xLvEu8YJ4QbwgXhAvNBXEC@Jp@uIdL7dIzK0Ok7IwKQuTsjApC5NyMCkDkzIwKf@Ssi8p@5KyLyn7vtrg9/H57y0Dc8vAXK0qtxrMrQZztarcojC3KMzVqpLaMKkNE60qqRGTGjHRqpJaMdGqEq0qqR2T2jHRqpIaMqkhE60qqSWTWjLRqpKaMqkpE60qqS2T2jLRqhKtKqk1E60qqTmTmjPRqpLaM6k93y3xrj454l3iXeJd4l3iXeIF8YJ4QbwgXmgqiBfEC@IF8TSd@Ym3NW5ujZtb4@bWuLk1blLjJgJbUusmtW5S6ya1blLrJrVuUusmtW5S4yY1blLjvluuX@Jc@l36Xfpd@gX9Qm@efkG/oF9@@m1NnFsT5xbDucVwbvmb1L1J3ZvUu0l9m9S3SV2b1LVJPZvUs0kdm9SxSd2a1KtJvZrUqUldmtSlST2a1KNJHZrUoUn9mdSfSb2Z1Jnvlv7B@wjiBu9DH0l@@m9dmivW5ZanueVprliXVKlJlZqIdkm1mlSriWiXVK1J1ZqIdkn1mlSvifOVVLFJFZuId0k1m1Sz75Z@l36XfkG/0B9Bv6Bf0C/pl59@WwXnVsG5VXByI9dWwblVcG4VnFsFJwphUg0nVXBSBSdVcFIFJ1VwUgUnimFSDSfVcFIFJ1VwUgUnVXBSBScGXFINJ9VwUg0n1XBSBSdVcFIFJ4piUg0n1XBSDSfVcFINJ1VwUgW/W8YF44JxwbhkXPK6@rzzM5675LZ8zpUwk7I5KZeTcjkpl5NyOSmTkzI50SaTMjkpj5PyOCmL3y3jgt8H/530z0@cLZNzy@Rc7TK3Ws6tlnO1y9yiObdoztUuk9o5qZ0T7TKpoZMaOtEuk1o6qaUT7TLRLpPaOtEukxo7qbET7TKptZNaO9Euk5o7qbkT7TKpvZPaO9Eukxo8qcET7TKpxRPtMtEuk9o8qc0T7TKp0ZMaPdEuk1o9qdXfLfEu8YJ4QbwgXhAvNBXEC@IF8YJ4QbwkXhIviZfES@Jp@vMTbzlBLifI5QS5nCCXEyScIOEECSdIuEDCBRIukHCBhAskymvCCRJOkHCChBMknCDhBAknSDhBwgkSTpBwgYQLJFzg3XI9iZP0S/rlp99yhlzOkEsWcslCLkvIZQkJPUjoQUILElqQ0IGEDiQ0IKEBSfmflPtJuZ@U@UmZn5T3SXmflPVJWZ@U80k5n5TxSRmflO9J@Z6U60mZnpTpSXmelOdJWZ6U5alyfPgkh09yWFTDYho@0Xk@0XyPqy3ja7XeWpG3qOaLar6o5otqvqjmC3G3qOqLqr4Qd4vqvhB3iyq/qPKLKv@rDX4f/D70e8Yl15Pf5@f3ywJqWUAtC6hlAbUsoJYF1LKAWhZQywIKFlCwgIIFFCygYAEFCyhYQMECChZQsICCBRQsoGABBQsoWEDBAgoWULCAggUULKBgAQULKFhAwQIKFlCwgIIFFCygYAEFCyhYQMECChZQsICCBRQsoGABBQsoWEDBAgoWULCAggUULKBgAQULKFhAwQIKFlCwgIIFvFviJfGSeEm81NwSL4mXxNPyqE@8ZRW1dKKWThQ8ouARBX8o@EPBGwreUPCFQhsv@ELBFwqeUPCEgh8U/KDgBQUvKPhAwQfeLb9PxtXn98sTanlCrXZeSxdq6UKtdl6rndeSh1rtvOAQBYcotPOCSxTaeaGdF9yi4BaFdl5wjIJjFNp5wTUKrlFo5wXnKDhHoZ0X2nnBQQrtvOAiBRcptPOCkxTaeaGdFxyl4CiFdl5wlYKrFNp5wVkKzlJo5wV3KbhLoZ0X2nnBZQrtvOA0Bad5t5oK4gXxgnhBvCBeEi@Jl8RL4iXxUnNLvCReEi@JV8TTcqlPvOVQtRyqlkPVcqhaDlVwqIJDFRyq4FAFhyo4VMGhCg5VcKiCQxUcquBQBYcquFPBnQruVHCngjsV3KngTgV3KrhTwZ0K7lRwp4I7vVv6Jf2SfkW/@vRbjlXLsWrJVS2rqmVVBZ0qTIWCThV0qqBTBY0q6FNBnwoToaBNBW0qaFNBmwq6VNCkgiYVNKmgRwU9KuhRQY8KWlSYAwUtKuhQQYMKGlTQoIIGFfTn3RIv6V/000dWn35Lk2rNhuKhomVLtZ5D4TkU5KnwHAoSVdzoUZCogkQVnkNBpgoyVXgOBakqSFXhPRTkqiBXhfdQkKyCZBUeREG2Cg@iIF0F6Xq3XE@uJ3GSfkW/ol99@vFsFQ9X8XQVj1fxfNWStFp2VsvOCnZWsLKClRVsrGBjBRsr2FjBxgo2VrCvgn0V7KtgXwX7KlhXwboK1lWwroJtFSyrYFkFyypYVsGyCpZVsKuCVRWsqmBVBasq2FTBpgo2VbCpgk0V7KlgTwV7KthTwZ4K9lSwpoI1vVvGJ@OT8cW4YlzxusV4zWd93v@yrlq6VUu3Cp5VeC0Fvyp4VcGrCj5V8KmCRxU8quBPBX8qeFPBmwreVPCmgi8VfKngR@@3xX8X/evz@@VNtbyp1muppU@19KnWa6llUbUsqtZrKchUQaYKr6UgVQWpKryWglwV5KrwWgqSVZCswmspyFbhtRReS0G@CvJVeC0FCStIWOG1FGSsIGOF11KQsoKUFV5LQc4KclZ4LQVJK0ha4bUUZK0ga4XXUngtBXkrvJaCxBUkrvBaCjJXkLnCaylIXUHqCq@lIHcFuXvPFfGSeEm8JF4SLzW3xEviJfGSeEW8Il4Rr4hXxCvilRYL8eodr5dE9pLIXkuol0s2XLLhkg2XbLhkc8NQwykbTtlwyoZTNpyy4ZQNp2w4ZcMpG07ZOEcNt2y4ZcMtG27ZcMt3y/XkenK9uF7667hen@vLQXs5aC/57CWfvayzl3U2dLOhmw3NbGhmQy8betnQyoZWNnSyoZMNjWxoZEMfG/rY0MaGNjZ0saGLDU1saGJDDxt62NDChhY2dLChgw0NbGhgQ/8a@tfQvob2NXSvoXsNzWtoXkPvGnrX0LqG1jV07t0yrnidYlzxOsU4zVB/xi0N7DWXetlgLxvsNZcaUtiQwsZcashhQw4bc6khiQ1JbMylhiw2ZLExmRrS2JDGxmRqSGNjLjXksSGPjbnUkMiGRDbmUkMmGzL5bumX9Ev6Jf2KfkW/0qdBv6Jff/otCe0lob0ktJeE9pLQXhLaS0J7SWgvCW1IaENCGxLakNCGhDYktCGhDQltSGhDQhsS2pDQhoQ2JLQhoQ0JbUhoQ0IbEtqQ0IaENiS0IaENCW1IaENCGxLakNCGhDYktCGhDQltSGhDQhsS2pDQhoQ2JLQhoQ0JbUhoQ0IbEtqQ0IaENiS0IaENCW1IaENCGxLakNCGhDYktCGhDQltSGhDQhsS2pDQhoQ2JLQhoe@WeEW8Il5psRCviFfEa@Jp@fUn3pLaXjbb8NeGvza8teGtDV9t@GrDUxue2nh7DS9teGnDRxv@2fDPhnc2vLPhmw3fbHhmwzPfLf3789/LO3t5Z6@310s/e729Xhbay0J7vb2GjDbeXkNKG1LakNLG22tIaePtNeS0IaeNt9eQ1Mbja8hqQ1YbstqQ1cbja7y9hrQ2pLW5060hr43H15DYhsQ2JLYhsY3H15DZhsw2ZLbx@BpS23h8DbltyG1Dbhty23h8Dcl9t4xPxifjinHFuGJcMa40OYwrXrcY34xvxmu@@zN@SXMvae4lzb2kuZc0N6S5Ic0NaW5Ic@M8NuS5Ic8NeW7Ic0OeG/LckOeGPDfkuSHPDXluSHNDmhvS3JDmhjQ3pPnd0i/ol/RL@iX9kn5Jv6Jf0a/0adCv6Nf0a/r1p9@S7F6S3cuue9l1r/fZy64bWt2Yng2tbszOhlY3tLqh0w2dbkzNhlY3dLqh042J2dDnhj439LkxKxv63NDnhjY3tLmhzY0p2dDmhjY3JmRDmxu63NDlxnRsTMeGJjf0uKHHDT1u6HFDjxt6/P70iF@MK@IX44r4xbjidZpxzes04zRj/RnH18rwvTJ8scyy6V7zsjEtG9OyIdcNuW7My4ZkNyS7MS8bst2Q7YZsN2S7MS0b0t2Q7sa0bMh3Q76bGxkbEt6Ylg0Jb0h4Y1o2pmVDyt8t/Yp@Rb/SX8/15npzvbnenzhL4ntJfC@J7yXxvSS@l8T3kvheEt9L4hsS35D4hsQ3JL4h8Q2Jb0h8Q@IbEt@Q@IbENyS@IfENiW9IfEPiGxLfkPiGxDckviHxDYlvSHxD4hsS35D4hsQ3JL4h8Q2Jb0h8Q@IbEt@Q@IbENyS@IfENiW9IfEPiGxLfkPiGxDckviHxDYlvSHxD4hsS35D4hsQ3JL4h8Q2Jb0h8Q@IbEt@Q@IbENyS@IfENiW9IfEPiGxLfkPiGxDckvkXih@U4IHpYlgOyh@U5bGvDMh0QPs9y7Xe8WVFgVg0YZIBBBhhkgEEGGOj/QPsH2j/Q/YHmDzR/oPkDzR/o/UDrB1o/0PmBxg80fqDxA43/apvf9@e/l9bP0vpZa3mW3c@y@1lreZbdz3rKA8kfSP7gKQ8e8kDyB5I/eMgD2R/I/kD2B7I/eMcD6R8844HsD17xQPoH0j94xQP5HzzigfwP5H8g/wP5H8j/QP4HT3gQAQYRYPCEBxFg8IIHEWDwgAcxYPB@BzFgEAMG73cQBQZRYBAFBq93EAUGUWDwegdR4N0yrnj9Ynzx@kWcYlzzus34ZnwzvhnXmm1ev3l9rZf5xFmRYVZkmBUZZkWGWZFhEBkGkWEQGQaRYRAZBpFhEBcGcWEQFwZxYRAXBnFhEBcGcWFwpgeRYRAZBpFhEBkGkWEQGQaRYRAZBpFhEBkGkWEQGQaRYRAXBnFhEBcGcWEQFwZx4d3Sr@nX9Gv6zaffihCzIsSs@jCrPszKDrOyw6A3DHrDoDMMOsOgLwz6wqArDLrCoCcMesKgIww6wqAfDPrBoBcMOsGgEwz6wKAPDLrAoAsMesCgBww6wKADDPx/4P8D7x94/8D3B74/8PyB5w/8fuDzA58fePzA4wf@PvD3gbcPvH3g6wNfH3j6wNMHfv5uGde8TjOueZ1mnGZ0PuOW18@a1bP0ftasnjWrB7I/kP3BrB5I/0D6B7N6IP8D@R/M6kEEGESAwawezOpBFBhM60EcGMSBwbQezOrBrB7EgkEsGMzqQTQYRIPBrB7Eg0E8GMzqQUQYRIR3q0@DfkW/pl/Tr@nX9Gv6Df3m029FiFkRYlaEmBUhZkWIWRFiVoSYFSEGEWIQIQYRYhAhBhFicMYHMWIQIQYRYhAhBhFiECEGEWIQIQYRYhAhBhFiECEG53wQIwYxYhAhBhFiECEGEWIQIQYRYhAhBhFiECGGG40HMWIQIwYxYhAjBhFiECEGEWIQIQYRYhAhBhFiECEGx30QIwYxYhAjBjFiECMGEWIQIQYRYhAhBhFiECEGEeLd8rqt2WV8M34YP4zXepnP@BUxZtWLWfVikC0G2WKQKwa5YpApBplikCcGeWKQJQZZYpAjBi9/kCMGOWKQIQYZYpAfBvlhkB0G2WGQGwa5YZAZBplhkBcGeeHd8vth3Hx@v7LDrOww6@3Pqg@z6sOstz8rQsyKELMW/6BFDFrEYPUPmsSgSQyW/6BNDNrEYPkPGsWgUQw3YA9axaBVDLcADJrFoFkMtwAM2sVwK8BwK8CgZQxaxnAD9qBpDJrGcGvAoG0M2sZwa8CgcQwax3AD9qB1DFrHcKvAoHkMmsdwq8CgfQzax3DLwKCBDBrIcMvAoIUMWshwC8FwC8GgjQy3EAwayaCRDDdgD1rJoJUMN2APmsmgmQy3FAzayaCdDLcWDBrKoKEMtxYMWsqgpbxb4hXxmnhNvCZeE6@J18Rr4rVWH/GaeEO8Id4Qb4g3xNNyn0@81WxmNZtZzWZWrBnugBhEm0G0GUSbQbQZxJpBrBnEmkGsGcSa4U7zQawZxJpBrBnEmkGsGcSaQaQZRJrhTolBrBnEmkGsGUSaQaQZRJpBpBlEmkGkGUSaQaQZRJpBpBlEmndLv@H66OP6XOfrk/n@ZL5AmW9Q5iuUV7YZ9JpBnxn0mUGXGXSZQY8Z9JhBfxl0l0F3GfSWQW8ZdJZBZxn0lUFfGXSVQVcZ9JRBTxl0lEE3GXSTQS8Z9JJBJxl0kkEXGfSQQQ8ZdJBBBxn0j0H/GHSPQfcY9I5B7xh0jkHnGPSNQc8Y9IxBxxh0jEG/GPSLd0v/Ie7Qf4g79NeMzn7ntb70Wt96ra@95nuvX0gfnx/Uw9TF1MfVx9XH1cfV5zwvpD5HfY76XPW56nPV56pPqE@oT6hPqE@qT6pPqk@qT6lPPX@5@pT6tPq0@rT6tPqM@oz6zPMRbh@@PPzFt4e/@PrwF98f/uILxF98g/iLrxB/8R3iL75E/KVvEX@ZJgWB5vODYpqCmqKawprimgKbIrsi@/NeFdkV2RXZFdkV2RXZFdkV@SjyUeTzfAyKfBT5KPJR5KPIR5GPIl9Fvop8Ffk@n7AiX0W@inwV@SryVeRQ5FDkUORQ5HgmT5FDkUORQ5FDkVORU5FTkVORU5HzWReKnIqcipyKXIpcilyKXIpcilyKXM@SU@RS5FLkVuRW5FbkVuRW5FbkVuR@VrMityKPIo8ijyKPIo8ijyKPIo8izwOUb6RsaL5x/8VX7r/4zv2XvnT/5UKOCwyuFe9a6K7V7FrErpXqWqCuVehafK4V5lpYrtXjWjSuleFaEK5Zd022a0ZdE@maLdckuWbC9eG6PlPXB@f6vL7@0tde48iBF2cOvDh04MWpAy@OHXhx7sCLgwdenDzw4uiBl84eeOnwgZdOH3gdfb5HmekoMx1lpqPMdJSZjibjKDMdZaajzHQ0T0eZ6WjCjjLTUWY6ykxHc3mUmY4m9SgzHWWmo8x0NN9Hmelo4o8y01FmOspMR2viKDMdLY6jzHSUmY4y09G6OcpMRwvoKDMdZaajzHS0to4y09EiO8pMR5npKDMdrb@jzHS0EI8y01FmOspMR2v0KDMdLdajzHSUmY4y09E6PspMRwv6KDMdZaajzHS01o8y09GiP8pMR5npKDMd4eEoMx1lpqPMdJSZjjLTEXiOMtMRio4y01FmOspMRwA7ykxHSDvKTEeZ6TyZ6fwtCl8bnLM6XhzW8eK0jtcFdxzb8dK5Ha8rLF1B6Ao5V4C5wskVPK5QcQWGKwxcLf2rFX@10K9W89Uivlq7V0v2aqVeLdCrdXm1HK9W4dXiu1pzV0vtaj1dLaOr1XO1aK7WytUSuVoZVwviah1cTf/VrF9N9tWMXk3k1fxdTdt9Juv903bnsJQXp6W8OC7lxUEpL52U8tJRKa9QwgvNVmi2QlktNFuhHBaapNAkhRJVKD@FJimUjUKzFZqtUMoJZZrQtIWySGi2QhkiNEmhSQolhlA@CM1WCP2h2QrNVgjiIWSHZiuE2tBshTAagmZotkJADOEvNFvxTFL87SS9thsH1Lw4oebFETUvzqh5cUjNS6fUvHRMzUvn1LxS05aathTIUtOWAlkKZKn5S81fCmQpkKXmL7WJpOYvNX8ptKWmLYW2FNpSIEuBLDV/qflLgSyVxlPzl0Jbav5S85dCWwptqflLoS01fym0pdCWmr9URk3BLgW71ESmYJfPjOYzo@@ftj/nBr04OOjFyUEvjg56cXbQi8ODXpwe9OL4oBfnB710gNBLJwi9dITQS2cIvXSI0EunCL10jNCrtCpK1UtpeZSql9I6KeG8tGBK1Utp5ZSQX1pCpeqltJZK1UtpUZWSQml1lbJDaZmVqpfSeivli9LCK1UvpRVYql5KS7GUSkprspRTSouzVL2UVmmpeikt11LeKeWdUvVSWsml6qW0pEu5qbS2S9VLaZGXklRptZeyVWnZl6qX0vov5a8SEErVSwkRpeqlBI1SaithpJTjSmApVS8l1JSqlxJ8SnmwhKNS9VICVCkzlpBVSpEliJWqlxLWSkmzBLpS9iyhr1S9lGBYql5KeKyneqkHmfVUL/VgtJ6sW3@L1te@AAdvvTh568XRWy@dvfXS4Vsvnb71aiGqBZsWWlqQaCGhtdxbq7y1lFsruLVMW6uztQRbK6@1vFqrqrV0WiumtSxaq6E15a2Zbk1naxZbU9WaodY0tD79fj7hfj7X9097lfPIXhxI9uJEshdHkr04k@zFoWQvTiV76aw7ziV76WCyl04me@lospfOJnvpcLKXTid76Xiyl84ne41y32imRrlvlPtGuW80iaPcN5rNUe4b5b5R7htN9Cj3jWZ8lPtGuW@U@0aLYZT7RqtilPtGuW@U@0YLZpT7RitnlPtGuW@U@0aLapT7RqtrlPtGuW@U@0YLb5T7RitwlPtGuW@U@0aLc5T7Rqt0lPtGuW@U@0YLeJT7Rit5lPtGuW@U@0aLfJT7Rqt9lPtGuW@U@0ZAGOW@ESJGuW@U@0a5bwSWUe4boWaU@0a5b5T7RoAa5b4Rska5b5T7RrlvBLpR7huh7xHIR7lvntw3DzLnyX3zYHSe3DdP7psn983fIvi1Z0SiwevkSR09@Zw9KendJL2bpHeT9G6S3k3Su0l6N0nvJsXdpLibFHeT4m5S3E2Ku0lxNynuJsXdpLibFHeT4m5S3E2Ku0lxNynuJqHdJLSbhHaT0G4S2k1Cu0loNwnt70/jZc9Pz0f1@r66IXSIp07x1PmdOsBTR3fq7E7p7Sa93SSzm2R2k7puUtdNorpJVDdp6SYt3SShmyR0k3JuUs5NgrlJMDfp5Cad3KSKm8Rwkxhu0sBNGrhJ@jZJ3ybF26R4m4Ruk9Bt0rdN@rZJ1jbJ2iY126Rmm0Rsk4ht0q5N2rVJsjZJ1ial2qRLm3RpkxxtkqNNKrRJhTaJzybx2aQ5mzRnk9RskppNCrNJYTYJyyZh2R49@fPTsxZez2J4Pavh9SyH17MevtcfCwpV2hzEo06bg3ip0yZ12rjP8vND6Qd1dvVx9XH1cfU5zyuq81Gfoz5Xfa76XAW86hzqE89bV594@ihgqnOqT6pPqk@pTylgqXOpT6tPq0@rTytgq/OozzwfqvrM8/G@ns/39XzAr@eDfX1Pw/ZDKNfhvDqdV8fz6nxeHdCrE3p1RK/O6H0O6X1O6X2O6TUJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrlJKDcJ5Sah3CSUm4Ryk1BuEspNQrk9Qrk9Qrk9Qvnnpwctrwcurwcvrwcwrwcxrwcyr@c1/gaOz2sASMR4HZltiPDPodnPqdkm8d0ktZukdpPCblLYTcK6SVg3CesmYd2kp5v0dJOMbpLRTeq5ST23q9Um9dwkmptEc5NWbtLKTRK5SSI3KeN2NakSxO3Rwe3RwT8/fV@d5zPaq6jkOlPc4if9/tImbdE27Wi8ApgifIdWDFMQUxRTGFMcf96I4riGu4a7hruGu4YfDT/PH6K3cRTnKM5RnKM4R3Gu4lzFuc8nojhXw6@GXw0PDQ8NDw0PDQ@9jVCcUJxQnFScVJxUnHxmRnFScVJxSsNLw0vDS8PrmVkNr2e43kYrTitOK04rTitOP0tEcVpxRnFGw0fDR8NHw@dZYs8aez2L7PWsstezzF7POns9C@31rLTXs9Re32v2ife9ar@XLesWS8KwJAxLwrAkDEvCZEmYLAmTJWGyJEyWhMmSMFkSJkvCZEmYnAiTE2FyIkxOhMmJMDkRJifC5ESYnAiTE2FyIiy1LmVJmCwJkyVhsiRMloTJkjBZEiZLwmRJmCwJkyVhsiRMloTJkjBZEiZLwuREmJwIkxNhciJMToTJibDHibDHibDHifj89EzD63vSnhHf08a84V0Y3oXhWRieheFVGF6FyaMweRQmR8JkRJiMCJP/YPIfTLaDyXYwuQ0mb8HkLZgsBZOlYHISTE6CyUAwGQgm38DkG5jsApNdYHIJTC6ByRwwmQMmK8DkAJgcAJPwbxL@TXq/Se83yfwmUd8k6pu0fJOWb5LwTRK@Sbk3Kfcmwd4k2Jt0epNOb5LnTfK8SZU3qfImDd4kvZukd5PiblLc7RHa7RHa7ZHX7ZHSPz89c/6aZ4V8rxV/fnrGfi9BFg6CvDV5CGHeEOatyUMS6E0CvbXykJR6k1JvrTwkyd4k2VsrD0m7N2n31kpIEvFNIr61EpLUfJOab62EJFnfJOtbKyFJ3zfp@9ZKSNL3rZWHJPSbhH5r5SEp/ibF31p5SNK/Sfq3Vh6SB2DyAKy1nckMMJkB1kpIcgVMrsD7h2cuXs9kvJ7ZeD3T8Xrm4/U9e8@I7/n7nkBmEGvBsBYMa8GwFgxrwbAWDEvBsBRMloLJUjBZCiZLweQkmJwEk4FgMhBMBoLJNzD5BibfwOQbmHwDk29gsgtMdoHJLjDZBSa7wGQOmMwBkzlgMgdM5oDJHDB5AiZPwOQJmDwBkydg8gRMVoDJATA5ACYHwOQAmIR/k/BvEv5Nwr9J@DcJ/ya936T3m/R@k95vkvlN6r5J3Tep@yZ136Tum9R9k6hvEvVNor5J1DeJ@iZR3yThmyR8k4RvkvBNEr5JuTcp9ybl3qTcm5R7k3JvEuztEeztEeztkentkentEeftEeftW5yfBz/z5NV5kDQPkuap6ubB1DwZdv4WXbvQHdnfkftdt9q79H6X3u/S@10yv0vdd6n7LnXfJeq7RH2XqO8S9V1avkvCd0n4LuXeJdi7BHvXLfIu5d4l2Lt0epdO75Ln/ZHn/ZHn/ZHn/ZHnP3//c5W/F8nekeydW@cd6d6R7p1b5x0J35HwnVvnXVK@6455l5TvkvJdd8y7NH2Xpu@6Y94l7rvEfdcd8y5x33WjvEvld6n8rhvlXXK/S@533Sjv0v1dur9L93fp/q774133x7ucANf98S5LwGUJuO6Pd3kDrtviXd6Ayxtw3RbvMglcJoHrtniXW@ByC1y3xbvcAtfd8C7bwGUbuO6Gd/kHLv/AdTe8y0hwGQkuI8FlJLhugnc5Ci5HwXUTvMtacN0E77oJ3mU2uO59d5kNLrPBde@7y3VwuQ6ue99d9oPLfnDd@@6yH1y3vLt8CJcP4brl3WVIuAwJ1y3vLmfC5Uz440z440x8fnoW@etZ5a9nmb@edf56FvrrWemv78gPeOyJ/A2fb/x8A@gbQd8Q@sbQN4i@4Q2McEQcR8RxRJz79R1nxOWMuJwRlzPickZczoi7sCmLxGWRuCwSl0XiskhcFonrJn@XV@LySlxeicsrcXklLq/Eddu/yzRxmSYu08RlmrhME3etfJkmLtPEZZq4TBOXaeIyTVyPBrjcE5d74nJPXO6Jyz1xuSeupwZcNorLRnHZKC4bxR8bxR8b5fPTMx2vZz5e37P3jPiev@8J/J7BZwqNOcSCcSwYx3pxrBfHcnEsF5fV4rJaXA6Ly2FxGSsuY8Xlp7j8FJeN4rJRXO6Jyz1xmSYu08Tllbi8EpdF4rJIXM6IyxlxGSIu@8Nlf7hcD5fr4TI7XGaHy@NweRwua8NlbbgcDZej4TIyXEaGy79w@Rcu28JlW7jcCpdb4TIpXCaFy5tweRMuS8JlSbgMCJfv4PIdXHaDy25wuQwul8FlLrjMBZen4PIU/LES/LES/DEQ/DEQ/LEN/LEN/DEL/DEL/LEIPj89USyen54o9ryDZ1n9zXpmYWE0OHf9O4aDYzg4d/27jAeX8eC6/d/lQLhu/3fd/u/yJFyehOv2f5c54brr32VOuMwJv0p5cilcLoXr9n@XXeGyK1y3/7t8C5dv4br932VguAwM1@3/LifD5WS4ngNwWRouS8P1HIDL23B5G67nAFwmh8vkcD0H4HI7XG6H6zkAl@3heg7AH//DH//j89MzC69nGl7fk/aM@J6273n7nrhn5uyZOmPucFEcF8VxURwXxXFRHBfFcVEcF8XlorhcFJeL4nJRXC6Ky0VxuSguF8XlorhcFNfzCi47xWWnuOwUl53islNcdorLTnHZKS47xWWnuOwUl53islNcdorLTnHZKS47xfW4g8tXcfkqLl/F5au4fBWXr@LyVVy@istXcfkqLl/F5au4fBWXr@LyVVy@istXcfkqHlrlMlhcBovLYHEZLC6DxWWwuAwWl8HiMlhcBovLYHEZLC6DxWWwuAwWl8HiMlhcj1@4nBaX0@JyWlxOi8tpcTkt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgt/jgtn5@eeN@r@3t5P@vb/BsoT7xvFLLGcW4cx8bl0LgcGpcx4zJmXH6My49xPRni8mNc7ovLdHGZLi6vxeWsuJwVl6HiMlRcPorLR3HZJy77xGWWuDwSl0fi8khcjojLEfHHCPHHCPHH/vDH/vDH9PDH9Hj/5M9YPgOMEMcIcR7icAwRxxBxHuJwjBHHGHEe4nAZJC6DxPUQh@shDpdl4nqIw@WduLwT10McLhPFZaK4HuJwuSkuN8X1EIfLVnE9xOF6iMNltLiMFtdDHC7HxeW4uB7icFkvLuvF9RCHy4NxeTCuhzhcZozLjHE9xOFyZVyujOshDpc947JnXA9xuHwal0/jeojD9RCHy7lxPcThsnBcFo7rIQ6Xl@PyclwPcbhMHZep43qIw@XuuB7icD3E4fJ7XH6P6yEOl/HjMn5cD3G4HCCXA@R6iMNlBbmsINdDHC5PyOUJuR7icJlDLnPI9RCHyyVyuUSuhzhcdpHLLnI9xOF6iMNlILke4nA5SS4nyfUQh8tScllKroc4/PGW/PGW/HmIwx@XyZ@HOPx5iMMf58kf5@nz0wOZ1/MafwPH5zW@AfmNyG9IfmPyG5TfqPyG5YNLe4Bp/o355zUebNoDzr/JOsAT78txPQ6q7EF5PAgTB/p5KNYPFdlhJzjksUO8Q7xLvEu8S7xLvEu8S7xLvEu8S7xLvCBeEC@IF8QL4gXxgnhBvCBeEC@Jl8TjFHvjiHfjPHPjcG/jsGnjXGfjYF/jlFvjTFbjeFPj/ErjKEjjbD/jIDvjVDbjCDLjyCrj9CfjeB7jqBrjIBTjVA/jWAXjgALjC@uNb1s3vrvb@CJq45t9je/INb7z1PiCTuPrHI3vGjS@O874GjXje6WM70RyvkDH@ZIX5wsnnK9WcB7pdp4Wdh5DdR5edB6Gch7ocR4GcG5Wd24Vdu5Ade5Kc@6rcu4hcW4ocLxcx8VzXAZHSXeENkdOccinwzCcysbZlx18OPhw8OHgw8GHgw8HHw4@HHw4@HDw4eDDwYeDDwcfDj4cfDj4cPDh4MPBh4MPBx8OPhx8OPhw8OHgw8GHgw8HHw4@HHw4@HDw4eDDwYeDDwcfDj4cfDj4cPDh4MPBh4MPBx8OPhx8OPhw8OHgw8GHgw8HHw4@HHw4@HDw4eDDwYeDDwcfDj4cfDj4cPDh4MPBh4MPBx8OPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPi74uODjgo8LPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@CnwU@CjwUeCjwEeBjwIfBT4KfBT4KPBR4KPAR4GPAh8FPgp8FPgo8FHgo8BHgY8CHwU@CnwU@CjwUeCjwEeBjwIfBT4KfBT4KPBR4KPAR4GPAh8FPgp8FPgo8FHgo8BHgY8CHwU@CnwU@CjwUeCjwEeBjwIfBT4KfBT4KPBR4KPAR4GPAh8FPgp8FPgo8FHgo8BHgY8CHwU@CnwU@CjwUeCjwEeBj9KR6zq9HHwU@CjwUeCjwEeBjwIfBT6qdYS7TkMnHvgo8FHgo8BHgY8CHwU@CnwU@OiXjr/mKGjw0eCjwUeDjwYfDT4afDT4aPDRpqOliQc@Gnw0@Gjw0eCjwUeDjwYfDT7adRAy8cBHg48GHw0@Gnw0@Gjw0eCjwUcfnRJMPPDR4KPBR4OPBh8NPhp8NPho8NFXx74SD3w0@Gjw0eCjwUeDjwYfDT4afHToQFbigY8GHw0@Gnw0@Gjw0eCjwUeDj04d@Ek88NHgo8FHg48GHw0@Gnw0@Gjw0aXTL4kHPlrHr@soch10rVObdWyuDqDVgaQ6TfM5m1EHDRIPfDT4aPDR4KPBR4OPBh8NPlrfef/SSXCcqQY@BnwM@BjwMeBjwMeAjwEfAz7GdEYb8cDHgI8BHwM@BnwM@BjwMeBjwMe4zvAiHvgY8DHgY8DHgI8BHwM@BnwM@JijA6yIBz4GfAz4GPAx4GPAx4CPAR8DPubq@CTigY8BHwM@BnwM@BjwMeBjwMeAjwmdFUQ88DHgY8DHgI8BHwM@BnwM@BjwMamzZIgHPgZ8DPgY8DHgY8DHgI8BHwM@pnRMC/HAx4CPAR8DPgZ8DPgY8DHgY8DHtM7B0BkOxNMZgTrzTQeU6TgrnbWks3N0jIzO1Rh9Adn3CQL6mvvnO7efr5d@vtf2@c7U59s4ny9xfL4V7vlqM30v0sueL9BXZH0fx0sP6b/0nPlLD9W@9IjlS4@3vfRk00uPXrz0fMHLn@8Jf0f@uz/@X3/3d//wlz//21/@559@8z//8k8//pff/PVP//3//Yc//fjjv/30wx9@@emH//bHX/3w8@9@@Lcffv3Df/3l3//Hb/7XL//7x3/8kSt/8D/@8Pc/@E8/vH71/v@v/vP/Bw) by processing the whole test set

---

## Alternate version, Score = 8426

A modified version to reach a total penalty of 2330. But it's not worth it...

- Code size = 171 bytes
- Total penalty = 2330
- Score = round(171<sup>1/4</sup> * 2330) = 8426

Same I/O format as the main version.

```javascript
f=(a,r=[k=5e3])=>k--?f(a,(i=Math.max(...a.map(n=>(g=n=>n?g(n>>1,n&1?++o:++z):o<z?o:z)(a=(p=a,n*([7007,7901,16239,32695,130527,261599][k]||k-5)),o=z=0))))>r[2]?r:[p,a,i]):r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZ3dkmy3caXv9RS8miBHR4ydCSB/NEMp/AB@AgYvaFv@GdmkQvJMOBR@d01X5bfQVIQOmr2BrOoCViLXWnsX/s@P/@/Hv/zjn//tT//5m59@/qc//O1v//zd1z9@@fN33//xu/OH9cM33/3uj7/5ze//@eN3X//bd3//43/@67f/8eN/ff3tt9/@@PHDn77@6bvfff0v3338@9Pv/@Xrn373O/vy0/@w3//61z//9te//us3v/35f//19z//9q/ffP3jd1//6bsfv/z0P7/@Pp8nv2Q/9sXCV39ZHn2@2HqO5xcPO90/fP/HH/77v//4m/PNN19@/u6v3z3ffPzvd3/@3n/4/Z9/@/2fvvz45d9@@Oa3f/7b33313Vff/@qrr773L/bDl@8X//rHv/v98/6yPv4975/P@/eH3@yPf@P9@/hyPv7N98/57pPvPvnuk1yNj3/r3afeV@v9@/qSH//2@/f9HtvvUf2@2lytj3/teXf6aNY0OU2/Gptr9o7w0axp9jRnmpgmp6lpNPx5tfMpfDRnmuSX79/Oh2Pz6Xw0a5o9zZkmpslpappm@EOrcO9A8znbfNAfzZmmucZFe1@debCZCJs5@GhymqILfe6Qd6@Zqo9mTXOmyWmaLvQxOtm718yszdTazK3N5NrMrs30fjQ5TU3TDH9oiWMEMiIZoe7LvYPNYrFZJzYL5fVLfjuDP9r372cF2Syhj2ZNs6c508Q0DKhpmuEPLXGMQEYkI5QRywh2X/4VzmeN@qxRnzXqs0Zf17hoXDUu2/v6rGGfNeyzeH0Wr89yddbpq6XvhLJ5O682aQnp7/6zrj@aNc2ZJqdpunDRuGpcNq77O8agwAcFPijwQYEPCnxQ4IMCHxT4oMBBgYMCBwWvlkhGKCOWEcyIZoQz4jnx9Pb8HW9Q5QOnjyb5Jb@dF9sE3QTbX/z9@4GZD8x8Ep4P2j6amCanqWmacQw0RpriMdYYbIw2hhvjXS/MeL0ff48fDPtg2AfDPhj2wbCDYQe7r5bLxnXnuhPE3/0G4z4Y9wG3D7h9UO2DagfODpwdGDswduD7ahk2r5zMVPLHJe8g7zvw97iBvc8m4YP@j6a5xkXjqnF5Xqt4rSJ2EfujfV@fLOGTJXyyhE@W8MkSPlnCJ0v4ZAmfLOFkCSdLOFnCyRJOlnCyhJMlnCzhyhLN22w@kmZSmo@mefvNvDd/RvMR9f1z/BVvTdZZk24WeWaRZxZ5ZpFnPlrn9/7@78k7a/LOmr1zTfpZk37W7J1r9s41yWjN3rnISYuc9GoJZEQyQhmxjGBGNCOcEc@J53pfxHPiOfGceE48J54TT3/eesejwpkcuCYHrsmBa3LgYqdf5MJFLlzkwkUuXOTCV0s/p5/Tz@m33v0oqyZnrkmWa5Llmiy5Jksu0uMiHS7S4SINLtLgIv0t0t@rpb8T1envxHX66x2t93uZNLmm@FiTLddkyzU1yCJpLpLmq6WXcd257lx3rjthnH5Lr/XuN0l2TZJdk2TXJNk1SXZNdl2TXRfZdZFdF9l1kVUXWXWRVRdZdZFNF9l0kU1fLeOccU7/xessvTXGrfe4ycJr0u@a9LvIu4vaaZF3F3l3kW8X@fbV8vvFuPX@/eThNXl4Ta21Jh2vScdraq01WXlNVl5Tay2S8yI5L2qtRZJeJOlFrbVI1otk/WoJZ8Rz4rneF/GceE48J54Tz4nnxHPiLeIt4i39ocRbxNPHsd7xZlNYsyms2RTWlIRr9obF3rDYGxZ7w2Jv@Gid685157rrOnGWXot@i37r3W/2kDV7yJrNY83msWbXWLNrLLaLxXax2B4W28JiW1hsB4vtYLENLLaBRfpfSvfNO23eafMhNh9e8477vuP1Grdnm9hTnO7ZLfYUp5tNY7NpbDaNzabx0TrXnevOdef6UnCuL66v9/XZZPZsMns2mT2bzJ5NZs8ms2eT2bPJ7NlkNpvMZpPZbDKbTWazyWw2mc0ms9lkNpvMZpPZbDKbTWazyWw2mc0ms9lkNpvMZpPZbDKbTWazybxa4i39ocRbxFvEW8RbxFvE08e13/Fm09qzW232p83@tNmXNvvSZj/a7EebfWizD71a@u/3f8@@tOH7U8vv2Z72bE97avk9u9SeXWpPLb/ZrDa1/KaW32xem81rU8tvNrHNJrap5Teb2WYz29Tym1p@s7m9WuI58Zx4TjwnnhNvEW8Rb@kPJd4i3iLeIt4i3iLeIt4mnj6@/Y6HUjKb6J5NdM8mumcT3Wyem81zwzw2m@hmE91soptNdLOJbjbRzSb6arm@uL64vrm@33Fmk92zye7ZXfdwlz2762Zb3WynG7Ky2VY32@pmO91sp5vtdLONvlriOf0WcRf9F3EX8Rb9N/30lve732yze8jOnt12z267h@xsNt3NprshPZvNd7P5bkjPZvN9tVx3ri@9FnEW/Rb9Fv02/Tb99rvfbNp7Nu09m/aeTXvPpr1n096zae/ZtPds2ptNe7Npbzbtzaa92bQ3m/Zm095s2ptNe7Npbzbtzaa92bQ3m/Zm095s2ptNe7Npbzbtzaa92bQ3m/Zm095s2ptNe7NpbzbtV0u8RbxFvE28TbxNvK1Pjnj6ePc73hQBe3b/Pbv/ZtvfbPub7X5DBTfb/Wa732zzm21@s71vtvePdvP7zbj9/v1s@3u2/T3Ucc/uv2f330Md9@z@ezjjpgjYFAEbzrjhjBuuuCkKNkXBhituioNNcbApDjbFwYYjboqEDUfccMRNsfB6x4xfvI@lv4Q4iziL8Yvxi/exiLOJs4mz9VEwfvM@NnH0@e1XnDNFyJki5EwRcqYIORQhhyLkUIQcipBDEXIoQg5FyKEIORQhhyLkUIQcipCPdnN9c31zfb@vT5Fypkg5U52cqU7OlCVnypJDPXKoRw51yKEOOdQfh3rjUG8c6oxDnXGoLw71xaGuONQVh3riUE8c6odD3XCoGw71wqul/yb@5v1s4m/G6S8@73FTZ5whx2fKjTPk@Aw5PhQfB1J8KD4OxceBFB@KkEMRciDFh2LkUIy8Wvot@i36ba5vrm@ub10nznn3myLmTBFzpog5U8ScKWLOFDFnipgzRcyZIuZQxByKmEMRcyhiDkXMoYg5FDGHIuZQxByKmEMRcyhiDkXMoYg5FDGHIuZQxByKmEMRcyhiDkXMoYg5FDGHIuZQxByKmEMRcyhiDkXMoYg5FDGHIuZQxLxafXLE28TbxNvE28TbxDvE03Scd7wpis5UQ2eqoYOWcCiHDmXQoQw6lD@H8udQ9hzKnkPZcyh7DuXOodx5tfo948779/hXGFg4WFMNndEazhRFZ4qiM5LDQWo41EaH2uhQGx1qo4PkcKiRDkLuoUY6SA6HWukgORxqpkPNdKiZDjXToWZ6tYxbjFuMW4zbjNuM2/oTGbcZtxm3GXcYdxinz@u8X3dqsDM12Jka7EzxdSi@DsXXofg6FF@H4uugfByKr0PxdSi@DsXXofg6FF2HoutQdB2KrkPR9Wrpd7h@9C7f16coO1OUnanGzlRjZ8qwM2XYof461F@HuutQdx3qrUO9daivDnXVoa461FOHeupQRx3qqEP9dKifDnXToW461EuH@uhQHx3qokNddKiHXq36E/8w7hD/ME6fyHmPmzrqjJhyppw6U06dEVMOVdWhqjqIKYfq6lBdHUSVQ5V1qLIOosqhyjqIKYdq61BtvVribPpt@m36bfpt@h36Hb15@p13v6nSzlRpZ6q0M1XamSrtTJV2Rqo5U6ydKdYOxdqhWDsUa4di7aDgHIq2Q9F2KNoORduhaDsUbQeB/1C8HYq3Q/F2KN4OxduheDsoPoci7lDEHYq4QxF3KOIORdxBAToUc4di7lDMHYq5QzF3KOZeLfG2PjnibeJt4m3ibeJt4h3iHeId4h3iHU0F8Q7xNH3nFS@mSIypDoOyMCgLg7IwKAuDcjAoA4MyMCj/grIvKPuCsi8o@z7aw@/P@7@nDIwpA2O0qphqMKYajNGqYorCmKIwRqsKasOgNgy0qqBGDGrEQKsKasVAqwq0qqB2DGrHQKsKasighgy0qqCWDGrJQKsKasqgpgy0qqC2DGrLQKsKtKqg1gy0qqDmDGrOQKsKas@g9ny1xNv65Ii3ibeJt4m3ibeJd4h3iHeId4h3NBXEO8Q7xDvE03TGO97UuDE1bkyNG1PjxtS4QY0bCGxBrRvUukGtG9S6Qa0b1LpBrRvUukGNG9S4QY37arm@ibPpt@m36bfpd@h39Obpd@h36BfvflMTx9TEMcVwTDEcU/4GdW9Q9wb1blDfBvVtUNcGdW1Qzwb1bFDHBnVsULcG9WpQrwZ1alCXBnVpUI8G9WhQhwZ1aFB/BvVnUG8Gdearpf/hfRziHt6HPpJ495@6NEasiylPY8rTGLEuqFKDKjUQ7YJqNahWA9EuqFqDqjUQ7YLqNaheA@crqGKDKjYQ74JqNqhmXy39Nv02/Q79jv4I@h36HfoF/eLdb6rgmCo4pgoObuSaKjimCo6pgmOq4EAhDKrhoAoOquCgCg6q4KAKDqrgQDEMquGgGg6q4KAKDqrgoAoOquDAgAuq4aAaDqrhoBoOquCgCg6q4EBRDKrhoBoOquGgGg6q4aAKDqrgV8u4w7jDuMO4YFzwuvq84z2eu@SmfI6RMIOyOSiXg3I5KJeDcjkok4MyOdAmgzI5KI@D8jgoi18t4w6/P/x30D/ecaZMjimTY7TLmGo5plqO0S5jiuaYojlGuwxq56B2DrTLoIYOauhAuwxq6aCWDrTLQLsMautAuwxq7KDGDrTLoNYOau1Auwxq7qDmDrTLoPYOau9Auwxq8KAGD7TLoBYPtMtAuwxq86A2D7TLoEYPavRAuwxq9aBWf7XE28Q7xDvEO8Q7xDuaCuId4h3iHeId4gXxgnhBvCBeEE/TH@94wwliOEEMJ4jhBDGcIOAEAScIOEHABQIuEHCBgAsEXCBQXgNOEHCCgBMEnCDgBAEnCDhBwAkCThBwgoALBFwg4AKvlutBnKBf0C/e/YYzxHCGGLIQQxZiWEIMSwjoQUAPAloQ0IKADgR0IKABAQ0Iyv@g3A/K/aDMD8r8oLwPyvugrA/K@qCcD8r5oIwPyvigfA/K96BcD8r0oEwPyvOgPA/K8qAsD5XjzSfZfJLNomoWU/OJ9v1E4zUup4zP0XpzRN6kmk@q@aSaT6r5pJpPxN2kqk@q@kTcTar7RNxNqvykyk@q/I/28PvD749@z7jgevD7eP9@WEAOC8hhATksIIcF5LCAHBaQwwJyWEDCAhIWkLCAhAUkLCBhAQkLSFhAwgISFpCwgIQFJCwgYQEJC0hYQMICEhaQsICEBSQsIGEBCQtIWEDCAhIWkLCAhAUkLCBhAQkLSFhAwgISFpCwgIQFJCwgYQEJC0hYQMICEhaQsICEBSQsIGEBCQtIWEDCAhIWkLCAV0u8IF4QL4gXmlviBfGCeFoe@Y43rCKHTuTQiYRHJDwi4Q8Jf0h4Q8IbEr6QaOMJX0j4QsITEp6Q8IOEHyS8IOEFCR9I@MCr5ffBuHz/fnhCDk/I0c5z6EIOXcjRznO08xzykKOdJxwi4RCJdp5wiUQ7T7TzhFsk3CLRzhOOkXCMRDtPuEbCNRLtPOEcCedItPNEO084SKKdJ1wk4SKJdp5wkkQ7T7TzhKMkHCXRzhOuknCVRDtPOEvCWRLtPOEuCXdJtPNEO0@4TKKdJ5wm4TSvVlNBvEO8Q7xDvEO8IF4QL4gXxAviheaWeEG8IF4QL4mn5ZLveMOhcjhUDofK4VA5HCrhUAmHSjhUwqESDpVwqIRDJRwq4VAJh0o4VMKhEg6VcKeEOyXcKeFOCXdKuFPCnRLulHCnhDsl3CnhTgl3erX0C/oF/ZJ@@e43HCuHY@WQqxxWlcOqEjqVmAoJnUroVEKnEhqV0KeEPiUmQkKbEtqU0KaENiV0KaFJCU1KaFJCjxJ6lNCjhB4ltCgxBxJalNChhAYlNCihQQkNSujPqyVe0D/pp48s3/2GJuWYDclDRcOWcjyHxHNIyFPiOSQkKrnRIyFRCYlKPIeETCVkKvEcElKVkKrEe0jIVUKuEu8hIVkJyUo8iIRsJR5EQroS0vVquR5cD@IE/ZJ@Sb989@PZKh6u4ukqHq/i@aohaTnsLIedJewsYWUJK0vYWMLGEjaWsLGEjSVsLGFfCftK2FfCvhL2lbCuhHUlrCthXQnbSlhWwrISlpWwrIRlJSwrYVcJq0pYVcKqElaVsKmETSVsKmFTCZtK2FPCnhL2lLCnhD0l7ClhTQlrerWMD8YH45NxybjkdZPxms98v/9hXTl0K4duJTwr8VoSfpXwqoRXJXwq4VMJj0p4VMKfEv6U8KaENyW8KeFNCV9K@FLCj15vi/9O@uf798ObcnhTjteSQ59y6FOO15LDonJYVI7XkpCphEwlXktCqhJSlXgtCblKyFXitSQkKyFZideSkK3Ea0m8loR8JeQr8VoSEpaQsMRrSchYQsYSryUhZQkpS7yWhJwl5CzxWhKSlpC0xGtJyFpC1hKvJfFaEvKWeC0JiUtIXOK1JGQuIXOJ15KQuoTUJV5LQu4ScveaK@IF8YJ4QbwgXmhuiRfEC@IF8ZJ4SbwkXhIviZfESy0W4uUrXg2JrCGRNZZQDZcsuGTBJQsuWXDJ4oahglMWnLLglAWnLDhlwSkLTllwyoJTFpyycI4Kbllwy4JbFtyy4JavluvB9eB6cj3113E939eHg9Zw0BryWUM@a1hnDess6GZBNwuaWdDMgl4W9LKglQWtLOhkQScLGlnQyII@FvSxoI0FbSzoYkEXC5pY0MSCHhb0sKCFBS0s6GBBBwsaWNDAgv4V9K@gfQXtK@heQfcKmlfQvILeFfSuoHUFrSvo3KtlXPI6ybjkdZJxmqF6jxsaWGMu1bDBGjZYYy4VpLAghYW5VJDDghwW5lJBEguSWJhLBVksyGJhMhWksSCNhclUkMbCXCrIY0EeC3OpIJEFiSzMpYJMFmTy1dIv6Bf0C/ol/ZJ@qU@Dfkm/evcbElpDQmtIaA0JrSGhNSS0hoTWkNAaElqQ0IKEFiS0IKEFCS1IaEFCCxJakNCChBYktCChBQktSGhBQgsSWpDQgoQWJLQgoQUJLUhoQUILElqQ0IKEFiS0IKEFCS1IaEFCCxJakNCChBYktCChBQktSGhBQgsSWpDQgoQWJLQgoQUJLUhoQUILElqQ0IKEFiS0IKEFCS1IaEFCCxJakNCChBYktCChBQktSGhBQl8t8ZJ4SbzUYiFeEi@JV8TT8qt3vCG1NWy24K8Ffy14a8FbC75a8NWCpxY8tfD2Cl5a8NKCjxb8s@CfBe8seGfBNwu@WfDMgme@WvrX@7@Hd9bwzhpvr4Z@1nh7NSy0hoXWeHsFGS28vYKUFqS0IKWFt1eQ0sLbK8hpQU4Lb68gqYXHV5DVgqwWZLUgq4XHV3h7BWktSGtxp1tBXguPryCxBYktSGxBYguPryCzBZktyGzh8RWktvD4CnJbkNuC3BbktvD4CpL7ahkfjA/GJeOSccm4ZFxqchiXvG4yvhhfjNd813v8kOYa0lxDmmtIcw1pLkhzQZoL0lyQ5sJ5LMhzQZ4L8lyQ54I8F@S5IM8FeS7Ic0GeC/JckOaCNBekuSDNBWkuSPOrpd@hX9Av6Bf0C/oF/ZJ@Sb/Up0G/pF/Rr@hX735DsmtIdg27rmHXNd5nDbsuaHVheha0ujA7C1pd0OqCThd0ujA1C1pd0OmCThcmZkGfC/pc0OfCrCzoc0GfC9pc0OaCNhemZEGbC9pcmJAFbS7ockGXC9OxMB0LmlzQ44IeF/S4oMcFPS7o8evTI34yLomfjEviJ@OS1ynGFa9TjNOM1XscXyvD98rwxTLDpmvMy8K0LEzLglwX5LowLwuSXZDswrwsyHZBtguyXZDtwrQsSHdBugvTsiDfBfkubmQsSHhhWhYkvCDhhWlZmJYFKX@19Ev6Jf1Sfz3Xi@vF9eJ6veMMia8h8TUkvobE15D4GhJfQ@JrSHwNiS9IfEHiCxJfkPiCxBckviDxBYkvSHxB4gsSX5D4gsQXJL4g8QWJL0h8QeILEl@Q@ILEFyS@IPEFiS9IfEHiCxJfkPiCxBckviDxBYkvSHxB4gsSX5D4gsQXJL4g8QWJL0h8QeILEl@Q@ILEFyS@IPEFiS9IfEHiCxJfkPiCxBckviDxBYkvSHxB4gsSX5D4gsQXJL4g8QWJL0h8QeILEl@Q@BKJb5Zjg@hmWTbIbpZns601y7RBeN/lWq94PaJAjxrQyACNDNDIAI0M0ND/hvY3tL@h@w3Nb2h@Q/Mbmt/Q@4bWN7S@ofMNjW9ofEPjGxr/0Ra/r/d/D63vofU91nIPu@9h9z3Wcg@77/GUG5LfkPzGU2485IbkNyS/8ZAbst@Q/YbsN2S/8Y4b0t94xg3Zb7zihvQ3pL/xihvy33jEDflvyH9D/hvy35D/hvw3nnAjAjQiQOMJNyJA4wU3IkDjATdiQOP9NmJAIwY03m8jCjSiQCMKNF5vIwo0okDj9TaiwKtlXPL6yfjk9ZM4ybjidYvxxfhifDGuNNu8fvH6Wi/9jjMiQ4/I0CMy9IgMPSJDIzI0IkMjMjQiQyMyNCJDIy404kIjLjTiQiMuNOJCIy404kLjTDciQyMyNCJDIzI0IkMjMjQiQyMyNCJDIzI0IkMjMjQiQyMuNOJCIy404kIjLjTiwqulX9Gv6Ff063e/ESF6RIge9aFHfeiRHXpkh0ZvaPSGRmdodIZGX2j0hUZXaHSFRk9o9IRGR2h0hEY/aPSDRi9odIJGJ2j0gUYfaHSBRhdo9IBGD2h0gEYHaPh/w/8b3t/w/obvN3y/4fkNz2/4fcPnGz7f8PiGxzf8veHvDW9veHvD1xu@3vD0hqc3/PzVMq54nWJc8TrFOM1ov8cNr@8xq3vofY9Z3WNWN2S/IfuNWd2Q/ob0N2Z1Q/4b8t@Y1Y0I0IgAjVndmNWNKNCY1o040IgDjWndmNWNWd2IBY1Y0JjVjWjQiAaNWd2IB4140JjVjYjQiAivVp8G/ZJ@Rb@iX9Gv6Ff0a/r1u9@IED0iRI8I0SNC9IgQPSJEjwjRI0I0IkQjQjQiRCNCNCJE44w3YkQjQjQiRCNCNCJEI0I0IkQjQjQiRCNCNCJEI0I0znkjRjRiRCNCNCJEI0I0IkQjQjQiRCNCNCJEI0I0Nxo3YkQjRjRiRCNGNCJEI0I0IkQjQjQiRCNCNCJEI0I0jnsjRjRiRCNGNGJEI0Y0IkQjQjQiRCNCNCJEI0I0IsSr5XVLs8v4Ynwzvhmv9dLv8SNi9KgXPepFI1s0skUjVzRyRSNTNDJFI0808kQjSzSyRCNHNF5@I0c0ckQjQzQyRCM/NPJDIzs0skMjNzRyQyMzNDJDIy808sKr5ffNuH7/fmSHHtmhx9vvUR961Iceb79HhOgRIXos/kaLaLSIxupvNIlGk2gs/0abaLSJxvJvNIpGo2huwG60ikaraG4BaDSLRrNobgFotIvmVoDmVoBGy2i0jOYG7EbTaDSN5taARttotI3m1oBG42g0juYG7EbraLSO5laBRvNoNI/mVoFG@2i0j@aWgUYDaTSQ5paBRgtptJDmFoLmFoJGG2luIWg0kkYjaW7AbrSSRitpbsBuNJNGM2luKWi0k0Y7aW4taDSURkNpbi1otJRGS3m1xEviFfGKeEW8Il4Rr4hXxCutPuIV8Zp4TbwmXhOviafl3u94o9n0aDY9mk2PWNPcAdGINo1o04g2jWjTiDWNWNOINY1Y04g1zZ3mjVjTiDWNWNOINY1Y04g1jUjTiDTNnRKNWNOINY1Y04g0jUjTiDSNSNOINI1I04g0jUjTiDSNSNOINK@Wfs311sf1vs7XJ/P9yXyBMt@gzFcoj2zT6DWNPtPoM40u0@gyjR7T6DGN/tLoLo3u0ugtjd7S6CyNztLoK42@0ugqja7S6CmNntLoKI1u0ugmjV7S6CWNTtLoJI0u0ughjR7S6CCNDtLoH43@0egeje7R6B2N3tHoHI3O0egbjZ7R6BmNjtHoGI1@0egXr5b@TdymfxO36a8Z7fnOa33ptb71Wl97zfdeP0gf7x/Uw9TF1MfVx9XH1cfVZ90XUp@lPkt9tvps9dnqs9XnqM9Rn6M@R31CfUJ9Qn1CfVJ98v7l6pPqU@pT6lPqU@rT6tPq0/cjnD58efjDt4c/fH34w/eHP3yB@MM3iD98hfjDd4g/fIn4o28Rf0yTgkDz/kExTUFNUU1hTXFNgU2RXZH9vldFdkV2RXZFdkV2RXZFdkVeirwUed2PQZGXIi9FXoq8FHkp8lLkrchbkbci7/sJK/JW5K3IW5G3Im9FPop8FPko8lHkcydPkY8iH0U@inwUORQ5FDkUORQ5FDnuulDkUORQ5FDkVORU5FTkVORU5FTkvEtOkVORU5FLkUuRS5FLkUuRS5FLkeuuZkUuRW5FbkVuRW5FbkVuRW5FbkXuC5RPpExovnH/4Sv3H75z/9GX7j8u5LjA4FrxroXuWs2uRexaqa4F6lqFrsXnWmGuheVaPa5F41oZrgXhmnXXZLtm1DWRrtlyTZJrJlwfruszdX1wrs/r4y995hpHDjycOfBw6MDDqQMPxw48nDvwcPDAw8kDD0cPPDp74NHhA49OH3iWPt@lzLSUmZYy01JmWspMS5OxlJmWMtNSZlqap6XMtDRhS5lpKTMtZaaluVzKTEuTupSZljLTUmZamu@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@n8cpKe6cYBNQ8n1DwcUfNwRs3DITWPTql5dEzNo3NqntC0haYtBLLQtIVAFgJZaP5C8xcCWQhkofkLbSKh@QvNXwhtoWkLoS2EthDIQiALzV9o/kIgC6Xx0PyF0Baav9D8hdAWQlto/kJoC81fCG0htIXmL5RRQ7ALwS40kSHYxZ3RuDP6@mn6c27Qw8FBDycHPRwd9HB20MPhQQ@nBz0cH/RwftCjA4QenSD06AihR2cIPTpE6NEpQo@OEXpSqyJVvaSWR6p6Sa2TFM5TCyZVvaRWTgr5qSWUql5SaylVvaQWVSoppFZXKjukllmqekmtt1S@SC28VPWSWoGp6iW1FFOpJLUmUzkltThT1Utqlaaql9RyTeWdVN5JVS@plZyqXlJLOpWbUms7Vb2kFnkqSaVWeypbpZZ9qnpJrf9U/koBIVW9pBCRql5S0EilthRGUjkuBZZU9ZJCTap6ScEnlQdTOEpVLylApTJjClmpFJmCWKp6SWEtlTRToEtlzxT6UtVLCoap6iWFx7zVS15k5q1e8mI0b9bNX6L1mRfg4K2Hk7cejt56dPbWo8O3Hp2@9ZQQVYJNCS0lSJSQUFrupVVeWsqlFVxapqXVWVqCpZVXWl6lVVVaOqUVU1oWpdVQmvLSTJemszSLpakqzVBpGkqfft1PuO7n@vpprnIe2cOBZA8nkj0cSfZwJtnDoWQPp5I9OuuOc8keHUz26GSyR0eTPTqb7NHhZI9OJ3t0PNmj88meVu5rzVQr97VyXyv3tSaxlftas9nKfa3c18p9rYlu5b7WjLdyXyv3tXJfazG0cl9rVbRyXyv3tXJfa8G0cl9r5bRyXyv3tXJfa1G1cl9rdbVyXyv3tXJfa@G1cl9rBbZyXyv3tXJfa3G2cl9rlbZyXyv3tXJfawG3cl9rJbdyXyv3tXJfa5G3cl9rtbdyXyv3tXJfCwit3NdCRCv3tXJfK/e1wNLKfS3UtHJfK/e1cl8LUK3c10JWK/e1cl8r97VA18p9LfRdgbyV@/rmvr7I7Jv7@mK0b@7rm/v65r7@JYKfOSMSDV4nT@royXv2pKR3k/Rukt5N0rtJejdJ7ybp3SS9mxR3k@JuUtxNirtJcTcp7ibF3aS4mxR3k@JuUtxNirtJcTcp7ibF3aS4m4R2k9BuEtpNQrtJaDcJ7Sah3SS0vz6Nx@5P96N6Pq9OCB3iqVM8dX6nDvDU0Z06u1N6u0lvN8nsJpndpK6b1HWTqG4S1U1auklLN0noJgndpJyblHOTYG4SzE06uUknN6niJjHcJIabNHCTBm6Svk3St0nxNineJqHbJHSb9G2Tvm2StU2ytknNNqnZJhHbJGKbtGuTdm2SrE2StUmpNunSJl3aJEeb5GiTCm1SoU3is0l8NmnOJs3ZJDWbpGaTwmxSmE3CsklYtqsnv3@6a@G5i@G5q@G5y@G56@Fz/bGgUKXNQTzqtDmIlzptUqeN@yzfP6R@UGdXH1cfVx9Xn3VfUZ2X@iz12eqz1Wcr4Fbnoz7nvnX1ObePAoY6h/qE@oT6pPqkAqY6p/qU@pT6lPqUApY6t/r0/VDVp@/H@9zP97kf8HM/2OdzGqYfQrkO59XpvDqeV@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@AytGKYgpiimMKY4ft@I4riGu4a7hruGu4YvDV/3D9HbWIqzFGcpzlKcpThbcbbi7PuJKM7W8K3hW8OPhh8NPxp@NPzobRzFOYpzFCcUJxQnFCfuzChOKE4oTmp4anhqeGp43pnV8LzD9TZKcUpxSnFKcUpx6i4RxSnFacVpDW8Nbw1vDe@7xO4ae@4ie@4qe@4ye@46e@5Ce@5Ke@5Sez7X7I33uWo/ly3rFkvCsCQMS8KwJAxLwmRJmCwJkyVhsiRMloTJkjBZEiZLwmRJmJwIkxNhciJMToTJiTA5ESYnwuREmJwIkxNhciIstC5lSZgsCZMlYbIkTJaEyZIwWRImS8JkSZgsCZMlYbIkTJaEyZIwWRImS8LkRJicCJMTYXIiTE6EyYmw60TYdSLsOhHvn@40PJ@Tdkd8ThvzhndheBeGZ2F4FoZXYXgVJo/C5FGYHAmTEWEyIkz@g8l/MNkOJtvB5DaYvAWTt2CyFEyWgslJMDkJJgPBZCCYfAOTb2CyC0x2gcklMLkEJnPAZA6YrACTA2ByAEzCv0n4N@n9Jr3fJPObRH2TqG/S8k1avknCN0n4JuXepNybBHuTYG/S6U06vUmeN8nzJlXepMqbNHiT9G6S3k2Ku0lxtyu02xXa7crrdqX09093zp@@K@Rzrfj96Y79XIIsHAR5K/IQwrwhzFuRhyTQmwR6K@UhKfUmpd5KeUiSvUmyt1IeknZv0u6tlJAk4ptEfCslJKn5JjXfSglJsr5J1rdSQpK@b9L3rZSQpO9bKQ9J6DcJ/VbKQ1L8TYq/lfKQpH@T9G@lPCQPwOQBWGk7kxlgMgOslJDkCphcgdcPdy6eOxnPnY3nTsdz5@P5nL074nP@PieQGcRaMKwFw1owrAXDWjCsBcNSMCwFk6VgshRMloLJUjA5CSYnwWQgmAwEk4Fg8g1MvoHJNzD5BibfwOQbmOwCk11gsgtMdoHJLjCZAyZzwGQOmMwBkzlgMgdMnoDJEzB5AiZPwOQJmDwBkxVgcgBMDoDJATA5ACbh3yT8m4R/k/BvEv5Nwr9J7zfp/Sa936T3m2R@k7pvUvdN6r5J3Tep@yZ13yTqm0R9k6hvEvVNor5J1DdJ@CYJ3yThmyR8k4RvUu5Nyr1JuTcp9ybl3qTcmwR7u4K9XcHerkxvV6a3K87bFeftU5zvi5@@ebUvkvoiqW9V1xdTfTNs/xJds9Ad2d@R@1232rv0fpfe79L7XTK/S913qfsudd8l6rtEfZeo7xL1XVq@S8J3Sfgu5d4l2LsEe9ct8i7l3iXYu3R6l07vkuf9yvN@5Xm/8rxfef7999@r/L1I9o5k79w670j3jnTv3DrvSPiOhO/cOu@S8l13zLukfJeU77pj3qXpuzR91x3zLnHfJe677ph3ifuuG@VdKr9L5XfdKO@S@11yv@tGeZfu79L9Xbq/S/d33R/vuj/e5QS47o93WQIuS8B1f7zLG3DdFu/yBlzegOu2eJdJ4DIJXLfFu9wCl1vgui3e5Ra47oZ32QYu28B1N7zLP3D5B6674V1GgstIcBkJLiPBdRO8y1FwOQqum@Bd1oLrJnjXTfAus8F177vLbHCZDa57312ug8t1cN377rIfXPaD6953l/3guuXd5UO4fAjXLe8uQ8JlSLhueXc5Ey5nwq8z4deZeP90F/lzV/lzl/lz1/lzF/pzV/rzGfmCx27kT/h84ucTQJ8I@oTQJ4Y@QfQJb2CEI@I4Io4j4tyv7zgjLmfE5Yy4nBGXM@JyRtyFTVkkLovEZZG4LBKXReKySFw3@bu8EpdX4vJKXF6JyytxeSWu2/5dponLNHGZJi7TxGWauGvlyzRxmSYu08RlmrhME5dp4no0wOWeuNwTl3vick9c7onLPXE9NeCyUVw2istGcdkofm0UvzbK@6c7Hc@dj@dz9u6Iz/n7nMDPGbxTaMwhFoxjwTjWi2O9OJaLY7m4rBaX1eJyWFwOi8tYcRkrLj/F5ae4bBSXjeJyT1zuics0cZkmLq/E5ZW4LBKXReJyRlzOiMsQcdkfLvvD5Xq4XA@X2eEyO1weh8vjcFkbLmvD5Wi4HA2XkeEyMlz@hcu/cNkWLtvC5Va43AqXSeEyKVzehMubcFkSLkvCZUC4fAeX7@CyG1x2g8tlcLkMLnPBZS64PAWXp@DXSvBrJfg1EPwaCH5tA7@2gV@zwK9Z4NcieP90o9i5P90odt/BXVa/WM8sLIwG565/x3BwDAfnrn@X8eAyHly3/7scCNft/67b/12ehMuTcN3@7zInXHf9u8wJlznhWylPLoXLpXDd/u@yK1x2hev2f5dv4fItXLf/uwwMl4Hhuv3f5WS4nAzXcwAuS8NlabieA3B5Gy5vw/UcgMvkcJkcrucAXG6Hy@1wPQfgsj1czwH49T/8@h/vn@4sPHcans9JuyM@p@1z3j4n7s6c3akz5g4XxXFRHBfFcVEcF8VxURwXxXFRXC6Ky0VxuSguF8XlorhcFJeL4nJRXC6Ky0VxPa/gslNcdorLTnHZKS47xWWnuOwUl53islNcdorLTnHZKS47xWWnuOwUl53islNcjzu4fBWXr@LyVVy@istXcfkqLl/F5au4fBWXr@LyVVy@istXcfkqLl/F5au4fBWXr@JHq1wGi8tgcRksLoPFZbC4DBaXweIyWFwGi8tgcRksLoPFZbC4DBaXweIyWFwGi@vxC5fT4nJaXE6Ly2lxOS0up8Wv0@LXafHrtPh1Wvw6LX6dFr9Oi1@nxa/T4tdp8eu0@HVa3j/deJ@r@3N53/Vt/gmUG@8ThaxxnBvHsXE5NC6HxmXMuIwZlx/j8mNcT4a4/BiX@@IyXVymi8trcTkrLmfFZai4DBWXj@LyUVz2ics@cZklLo/E5ZG4PBKXI@JyRPwaIX6NEL/2h1/7w6/p4df0eP3kdyyfAUaIY4Q4D3E4hohjiDgPcTjGiGOMOA9xuAwSl0HieojD9RCHyzJxPcTh8k5c3onrIQ6XieIyUVwPcbjcFJeb4nqIw2WruB7icD3E4TJaXEaL6yEOl@PiclxcD3G4rBeX9eJ6iMPlwbg8GNdDHC4zxmXGuB7icLkyLlfG9RCHy55x2TOuhzhcPo3Lp3E9xOF6iMPl3Lge4nBZOC4Lx/UQh8vLcXk5roc4XKaOy9RxPcThcndcD3G4HuJw@T0uv8f1EIfL@HEZP66HOFwOkMsBcj3E4bKCXFaQ6yEOlyfk8oRcD3G4zCGXOeR6iMPlErlcItdDHC67yGUXuR7icD3E4TKQXA9xuJwkl5PkeojDZSm5LCXXQxx@vSW/3pLfhzj8ukx@H@Lw@xCHX@fJr/P0/ulC5rmv8Qs43tf4BOQnIj8h@YnJT1B@ovITlheXdoFp/on5@xoXm3bB@YusAzzxvhzXY6HKLpTHhTCxoJ@LYn1RkS12gkUeW8RbxNvE28TbxNvE28TbxNvE28TbxNvEO8Q7xDvEO8Q7xDvEO8Q7xDvEO8QL4gXxOMXeOOLdOM/cONzbOGzaONfZONjXOOXWOJPVON7UOL/SOArSONvPOMjOOJXNOILMOLLKOP3JOJ7HOKrGOAjFONXDOFbBOKDA@MJ649vWje/uNr6I2vhmX@M7co3vPDW@oNP4OkfjuwaN744zvkbN@F4p4zuRnC/Qcb7kxfnCCeerFZxHup2nhZ3HUJ2HF52HoZwHepyHAZyb1Z1bhZ07UJ270pz7qpx7SJwbChwv13HxHJfBUdIdoc2RUxzy6TAMp7Jx9mUHHw4@HHw4@HDw4eDDwYeDDwcfDj4cfDj4cPDh4MPBh4MPBx8OPhx8OPhw8OHgw8GHgw8HHw4@HHw4@HDw4eDDwYeDDwcfDj4cfDj4cPDh4MPBh4MPBx8OPhx8OPhw8OHgw8GHgw8HHw4@HHw4@HDw4eDDwYeDDwcfDj4cfDj4cPDh4MPBh4MPBx8OPhx8OPhw8OHgw8GHg48FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8FPhb4WOBjgY8NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48NPjb42OBjg48DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8DPg74OODjgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@AjwEeAjwEeAjwAfAT4CfAT4CPAR4CPAR4CPAB8BPgJ8BPgI8BHgI8BHgI8AHwE@AnwE@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4SPCR4CPBR4KPBB8JPhJ8JPhI8JHgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT5SR67r9HLwkeAjwUeCjwQfCT4SfCT4yNIR7joNnXjgI8FHgo8EHwk@Enwk@EjwkeCjHh1/zVHQ4KPAR4GPAh8FPgp8FPgo8FHgo0xHSxMPfBT4KPBR4KPAR4GPAh8FPgp8lOsgZOKBjwIfBT4KfBT4KPBR4KPAR4GPWjolmHjgo8BHgY8CHwU@CnwU@CjwUeCjto59JR74KPBR4KPAR4GPAh8FPgp8FPioowNZiQc@CnwU@CjwUeCjwEeBjwIfBT4qdOAn8cBHgY8CHwU@CnwU@CjwUeCjwEelTr8kHvgoHb@uo8h10LVObdaxuTqAVgeS6jTNezajDhokHvgo8FHgo8BHgY8CHwU@CnyUvvP@0UlwnKkGPhp8NPho8NHgo8FHg48GHw0@2nRGG/HAR4OPBh8NPhp8NPho8NHgo8FHu87wIh74aPDR4KPBR4OPBh8NPhp8NPjopQOsiAc@Gnw0@Gjw0eCjwUeDjwYfDT566/gk4oGPBh8NPhp8NPho8NHgo8FHg48@OiuIeOCjwUeDjwYfDT4afDT4aPDR4KNDZ8kQD3w0@Gjw0eCjwUeDjwYfDT4afHTqmBbigY8GHw0@Gnw0@Gjw0eCjwUeDjy6dg6EzHIinMwJ15psOKNNxVjprSWfn6BgZnavR@gKyzxME9DX39zu379dL3@@1vd@Zer@N836J4/1WuPvVZvpepMfuF@grsr6P49FD@o@eM3/0UO2jRywfPd726MmmR49ePHq@4PH7PeGvyL/64X/96lf/@PNPf/n53//w7b///C9f/923f/7DP/3ff/zD11//5ctX3//45at/@OGbr7773Vd/@erXX/39j//5r9/@x4//9fU/f82V7/2Hr37zlX/56vnm9f9v/vb/AQ)

It includes some hardcoded values for the highest multipliers. They were found by generating all bitmasks **m** with up to 32 bits and no more than 5 0's, keeping the values for which **m mod p = 0**, checking the score of **q * m / p** and finally doing the same operation with the inverted bitmask of **m** of the same length (no more than 5 1's with all other bits set to 0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), Score = 7702

```julia
g(x,b=[bin(x)...])=min(sum(b.=='0'),sum(b.=='1'))
f(a,b)=((r,i)=findmin(map(i->max(g(a*i),g(b*i)),1:10^5));[r,a*i,b*i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvBCsIwEETv/kh2ZA3NQQ/K@iOlwi7SsGKKtBTy9zFePM28ecxrf7teWstU2WQ0X6gixjhBSu/bXsiiSBgC@A8pAIeZlA1CtLJDZl@ev0PRD/npXrRSJj06OJP1AKdrGh5n4Dau3AX3dUJrXw)

A naive and slow solution. Output of `f` is `[f(p,q),p',q']`

- Length = 119 bytes
- Penalty = 2332
- Score = round(119^.25*2332) = 7702

To run this on the test set, I've downloaded the paste bucket as a `txt` file called `results.txt`
and removed the last row. I used this code to evaulate the penalty using all cores of my machine:

```julia
all_res = open("results.txt","r") do f
    map(row->parse.(Int,split(split(row," ")[1], "/")), readlines(f))
end

addprocs(7)
@everywhere g(x,b=[bin(x)...])=min(sum(b.=='0'),sum(b.=='1'))
@everywhere f(a,b)=((r,i)=findmin(map(i->max(g(a*i),g(b*i)),1:10^5));[r,a*i,b*i])

penalty = @parallel (+) for iter in all_res
    max(f(iter[1],iter[2])[1]-2,0)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (GCC), score = 11222

- Length: 538 (<-- less verbose than Java)
- Penalty: 2330

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;uint32_t f(uint32_t x){int s=__builtin_popcount(x);return min(s,32-__builtin_clz(x)-s);}int i(vector<int>const&a,vector<int>const&b){int i=0,j=0;while(i<a.size()&j<b.size()){if(a[i]==b[j])return a[i];else++(a[i]<b[j]?i:j);}return 0;}int main(){vector<array<vector<int>,6>>T(1024);int p,q,a;for(a=1;a<1024;++a){for(unsigned m=1;m<500000;++m)for(p=f(a*m);p<6;++p)T[a][p].push_back(m);}while(cin>>p>>q){for(a=1;;++a){unsigned m=i(T[p][a],T[q][a]);if(m){cout<<p*m<<' '<<q*m<<' '<<a<<'\n';break;}}}}
```

Runs in 5 seconds on my machine.

Input format: something like this

```cpp
2 1
3 1
3 2
4 1
4 3
5 1
5 2
```

Output format: something like this

```cpp
2 1 1
3 1 1
3 2 1
4 1 1
4 3 1
5 1 1
5 2 1
```

(`p', q', f(p', q')` on each line)

---

Ungolfed code:

```cpp
/* the program will not work without END_ANS and END_INPUT being 
correctly set but it can be easily calculated by a naive algorithm
END_ANS must be greater than all of the answers,and END_INPUT
must be greater than all of the inputs */
int constexpr END_ANS=6,//<-- according to the naive algorithm
END_INPUT=1024,END_M=4194304;
/* END_M is an parameter to the algorithm. As this gets larger,
the algorithm takes more resource but the answer gets better.
NOTE: (END_INPUT-1) * (END_M-1) must not overflow integer.
*/

static_assert((END_INPUT-1)*(long long)(END_M-1)<4294967296LL);

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<array>
#include<algorithm>

uint32_t f(uint32_t x){
    uint32_t len=32-__builtin_clz(x),
    sum=__builtin_popcount(x);
    return std::min(sum,len-sum);
}

/**Return a common value between two vectors,or 0 if not found.
The input vectors must be sorted.*/
int intersect(std::vector<int>const&a,std::vector<int>const&b){
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(i<a.size()&j<b.size()){
        if(a[i]==b[j])return a[i];
        else++(a[i]<b[j]?i:j);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<std::vector<int>,END_ANS>>T(END_INPUT);
    //T[i][f1] = all values of m s.t. f(i*m) <= f1
    for(int i=1;i<END_INPUT;++i){
        for(unsigned m=1;m<END_M;++m)
            for(int fi=f(i*m);fi<END_ANS;++fi)
                T[i][fi].push_back(m);
    }

    // THIS PART IS USED FOR CALCULATING SCORE
    int score=0;

    int p,q;while(std::cin>>p>>q){
        for(int ans=1;;++ans){
            unsigned m=intersect(T[p][ans],T[q][ans]);
            if(m){
                std::cout<<p*m<<' '<<q*m<<' '<<ans<<'\n';

                // THIS PART IS USED FOR CALCULATING SCORE
                score+=std::max(ans-2,0);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // THIS PART IS USED FOR CALCULATING SCORE
    std::cerr<<score<<'\n';

}
```

---

Note: There are some hardcoded constants in the program (maximum input value, maximum `ans`, etc.) I assume it's allowed because otherwise most programs can work in 32-bit integer range anyway.

For each `(p,q)` pair, the program tests all pairs `(p×m,q×m)` for all `m` in range `[1,MAX_M[` and find the optimal value, in a smart way.

Because the result is the same for `MAX_M=500000` and `MAX_M=4194304` (the largest value such that all intermediate computations still fit in an `uint32_t` (unsigned 32-bit integer)), I just use `MAX_M=500000` so the program runs faster.

Bash+Jelly script to calculate score:

```cpp
jelly eun 'ỴḲṛ/VƊ€_2»0S' "'''$(cat result.txt)'''" # <- weird input format
```

---

tl;dr: Tested all values of `m` up to `4194304` (exclusive), best penalty so far = `2330`.

Comment: I may be able to kill a few more bytes by changing between `unsigned`, `uint32_t` and `int`, but it's not very important anyway.

Comment: Extended to 60000000 (6e7) now.

Comment: I think I have an idea how to find the optimal solution...

Comment: Yes, the optimal value is 2330.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7437

- Code size = 10 bytes
- Total penalty = 4182
- Score = round(10<sup>1/4</sup> * 4182) = 7437

Takes input as **[p, q]**, returns **[f(p, q), [p', q']]**.

```
BC,Bḅ1ZṀṂ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/JWcfp4Y5Ww6iHOxse7mzS@f//f7SZoY6JQSwA)

#### How?

This code simply computes **f(p, q)** without trying to apply any multiplier.

```
BC,Bḅ1ZṀṂ, - main link taking [p, q]              --> e.g. [61, 40]
B          - convert to binary                    --> [[1,1,1,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0,0,0]]
 C         - 1-complement                         --> [[0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1,1,1]]
   B       - convert to binary again              --> [[1,1,1,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0,0,0]]
  ,        - pair                                 --> [ [[0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1,1,1]],
                                                        [[1,1,1,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0,0,0]] ]
    ḅ1     - convert from unary base,             --> [[1, 4], [5, 2]]
             which effectively sums the lists
      Z    - zip, so that number of 0-bits and    --> [[1, 5], [4, 2]]
             number of 1-bits are paired together
       ṀṂ  - maximum of the minimum               --> max(min(1, 5), min(4, 2)) =
                                                      max(1, 2) =
                                                      2
         , - pair with the input to comply with   --> [2, [61, 40]]
             the expected output format
```

Comment: ````````````:|```````````` TODO convex hull optimization ...

Comment: (why don't you `S` to sum?)

Comment: @user202729 There must be a way to have it working with `S` but I'm not sure how to do it. Applying `S` on e.g. `[[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]` will result in `[1,1,0,1]`, which is not what I want. (Disclaimer: I have little to no experience in Jelly.)

Comment: ... Either `ZS` or `S€`, which doesn't really help.